# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG error while running a TestNG file

Tags: eclipse, exception, intellij-idea, testng, noclassdeffounderror

Upon running a TestNG file in the Intellij community edition I am getting the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is a project which I imported from the GITHUB, which is previously coded through the Eclipse IDE. In the Eclipse IDE same TestNG file was running successfully.

Is there any configurations that I need to do before running a imported source code in IntelliJ? I am new to IntelliJ, so do not have much idea on this.

Comment: Have you imported or downloaded all dependencies for the project? The above error means org.testng.TestNG is missing .

Comment: Does project use Maven or Gradle? Can you provide a project to check?

Comment: Thank you both, yes after I did the Maven -> Clean an update the project issue was resolved.